# how to slow down listing hover effect using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am a poor programmer can some 1 help me out with this problem.when i mouseover on "when you click here" rest of the `ul` slides down when i mouse out slide up up till here its working good .but when i mouseover on mu `ul` "we" text it needs to stay and when i mouse out from the text "we" it should slide up.but in my code when i mouseover on text "we" it stays when i mouse out it stays back insted of sliding up.can any one help me please.here is js fiddle for [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/LFKxF/)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
//alert('fdsafdasfdas');

$("#aaaaa").mouseover( function() {
//alert('ssss');
var lis = $(this).next('ul').find('li');

$(lis).each(function(index) {
var li = $(this);

setTimeout(function() {
li.slideDown(1000);
}, 10 * index);
});
});
$("#aaaaa").mouseout( function() {
//alert('ssss');
var bu=$(this).next('ul').find('li');
$(bu).each(function(index) {
var bu1 = $(this);

setTimeout(function() {
bu1.slideUp(1000);
}, 10 * index);
});
});

$("#dropdown").mouseout( function() {
//alert('out');
var bu=$(this).next('ul').find('li');
$(bu).each(function(index) {
var bu1 = $(this);

setTimeout(function() {
bu1.slideUp(1000);
}, 10 * index);
});
});



$("#bag").mouseenter( function() {
    $("#aaaaa").mouseout( function() {
//alert('opopopopopopo');
var bu=$(this).next('ul').find('li');
$(bu).each(function(index) {
var bu1 = $(this);

setTimeout(function() {
bu1.stop(1000);
}, 10 * index);
});
});
//alert('ssss');
setTimeout(function() {
bu1.delay(5000);
}, 10 * index);
});
$("#bag").mouseout( function() {
var bu=$(this).next('li');
$(bu).each(function(index) {
var bu1 = $(this);

setTimeout(function() {
bu1.slideUp(1000);
}, 10 * index);
});
});

});

</script>
#dropdown li {
display:none;
}
<div id="dropdown" style="width:200px; border:solid 1px #000;">

<div id="aaaaa">when you click here</div>

<ul id="bag" style="width:200px;position:relative;top:-10px;">
<li id="bag">We</li>
<li id="bag">We</li>
<li id="bag">We</li>
<li id="bag">We</li>
<li id="bag">We</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: rephrase your question please and add some spaces.

Comment: You are also missing double quote near end of line `<ul id="bag" style="width:200px;position:relative;top:-10px;>`

Comment: Also why are you loading two jquery's ?

Comment: Why on the earth you gave same id every `ul` `li` element? http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Comment: my intention is to stay when i mouseover on the ul part i.e text "we",slide up when i mouse out of the text "we"

Comment: Never use the same id multiple times. Only the first occurance of this id in the DOM is valid. Check if my example do what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#aaaaa").mouseenter( function() {
    $("#bag").slideDown(1000);
});

$("#aaaaa").mouseleave( function() {
    $("#bag").slideUp(1000);
});
});
</script>
```

Here the clean code lines (incl HTML): http://jsfiddle.net/LFKxF/11/

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you are using same id multiple times. Here is working example :

```
        <div id="dropdown" style="width:200px; border:solid 1px #000;">

    <div id="aaaaa">when you click here</div>

    <ul class="notused" style="width:200px;position:relative;top:-10px;">
    <li class="bag">We</li>
    <li class="bag">We</li>
    <li class="bag">We</li>
    <li class="bag">We</li>
    <li class="bag">We</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

And the javascript:

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //alert('fdsafdasfdas');


    $("#aaaaa").mouseout( function() {
    //alert('ssss');
    var bu=$(this).next('ul').find('li');
    $(bu).each(function(index) {
    var bu1 = $(this);

    setTimeout(function() {
    bu1.slideUp(1000);
    }, 10 * index);
    });
    });

    $("#dropdown").mouseout( function() {
    //alert('out');
    var bu=$(this).next('ul').find('li');
    $(bu).each(function(index) {
    var bu1 = $(this);

    setTimeout(function() {
    bu1.slideUp(1000);
    }, 10 * index);
    });
    });



    $(".bag").mouseenter( function() {
        $("#aaaaa").mouseout( function() {
    //alert('opopopopopopo');
    var bu=$(this).next('ul').find('li');
    $(bu).each(function(index) {
    var bu1 = $(this);

    setTimeout(function() {
    bu1.stop(1000);
    }, 10 * index);
    });
    });
    //alert('ssss');
    setTimeout(function() {
    bu1.delay(5000);
    }, 10 * index);
    });
    $(".bag").mouseout( function() {
    var bu=$(this).next('li');
    $(bu).each(function(index) {
    var bu1 = $(this);

    setTimeout(function() {
    bu1.slideUp(1000);
    }, 10 * index);
    });
    });
    });

    </script>
```

Just use class "bag" instead of the same id multiple times. I hope it helps.

Comment: Like this it works like you are expecting. You can test it in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Tested this a bit and had some issues with using mouse(over|out) triggering multiple times as you move the mouse around inside of #dropdown.

jQuery has mouseenter and mouseleave which fixed the issue for me.

Let me know how it goes.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var index = 100;

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#dropdown").mouseenter(function()
        {
            var d = new Date();
            console.log('dropdown mouseover' + d);
            $('#bag').slideDown(1000);

            return;

            // You will need the debounce plugin if you want the extra delay.
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#bag').slideDown(1000);
            }, 10 * index);
        });

        $("#dropdown").mouseleave(function()
        {
            var d = new Date();
            console.log('dropdown mouseout' + d);

            $('#bag').slideUp(1000);

            return;

            // You will need the debounce plugin if you want the extra delay.
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#bag').slideUp(1000);
            }, 10 * index);
        });

    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    #dropdown {
        background-color: red;
        width:200px;
        border: solid 8px #000;
    }

    #aaaaa {
        background-color: green;
        display: block;
    }

    #bag {
        background-color: yellow;
        display: none;
    }

    /* This is needed for some reason, the li's get display set to none. */
    #bag li {
        display: block;
    }
</style>

<div id="dropdown">
    <div id="aaaaa">when you click here</div>
    <ul id="bag">
    <li id="bag">We</li>
    <li id="bag">We</li>
    <li id="bag">We</li>
    <li id="bag">We</li>
    <li id="bag">We</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```